# With how many ways can we choose $6$ cards?

Tags: combinatorics

With how many ways can we choose, from  usual pack of cards with $52$ cards(that are separated into $4$ colours and $13$ kinds) $6$ cards (we don't care about the order),from which three are red($♢$ or $♡$) and three are black, and two of the three red are of the same kind (number)?

Is the result as followed?
$$\binom{13}{2} \cdot \binom{26}{1}+\binom{26}{3}$$

Comment: Just a random formula wouldn't get any points from me. Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: Note that there are cross-restrictions, for example if there are two hearts, they can't have the same value. The best way to solve such problems is to split into exclusive cases, represent each case as a sequence of decisions (because sequences are easy to count), and add up. Less space for error, can convince some skeptic that you have the right number.

Comment: I changed the grammar to make things more clear. Please roll back the change if it is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{26}{3}$ ways to 3 black cards.
There are 13 ways to choose the 2 red cards that have the same number.
There are 24 ways to choose the remaining red card.
So, there are 13 x 24 ways to choose 3 red cards where 2 of the cards have the same number.